# Access dynamic Filter a Textfield with a numberfield

Tags: vba, ms-access

my form looks like this:
[image: Form]

My problem is, that he "LeistungsBezeichnungsRef" isnt filtering. In my main form, I selected "13222", in addition i want to be shown at the subform just "13222" positions, not 20455, too.

This is my diagram:
[image]

The Idea is, that I got a cost centre (13222) to these cost centres it exists some Bills ( excavator, crane etc ) These Bills are cost centre specific! So i build up a table called "LV", where i can type in a position, amount, value etc and in " Leistungserfassung ", I can select a specific position and associate it with a Date/Daily report Number etc , selected in table "Räumstelle".

The field "LeistungsBezeichnungsRef" ( called like "position billing" in engl. ) Has this query:
[image: query of the field wihch has to be filtered]
I already wrote the Combobox-Fieldname of the mainform into the query criteria.. but its not filtering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `AfterUpdate` of the search `ComboBox` you must requery the subform

```
Private Sub SearchComboBox_AfterUpdate()
    TheSubform.Requery

    'Filter the combo in the subform
    TheSubform.Form!TheLVCombo.RowSource = "SELECT whatever FROM LV WHERE ID = " _
       & SearchComboBox.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay its working more or less. The problem I have is, that the     `LeistungsBezeichnungs` field is a number field, but due to the column choice it shows a text.. If I now say `Private Sub Kostenstelle_AfterUpdate() Me.Leistungserfassung.Requery Leistungserfassung.Form!LeistungsBezeichnung.RowSource = " SELECT ID FROM LV WHERE PosKostenstelle = " & KostenstelleRef.Value End Sub` It works, but shows the number , not a text.. how do I get it to SELECT the ID, but shows the desciption?    @Oliver Jacot-Descomber

Comment: `SELECT id, text FROM...`. Then you must format the ComboBox accordingly: Column Count = 2, Column Widths = "0cm" (makes id column disappear). Bound Column = 1. Limit To List = Yes. List Rows = 16.